# How to customize ngTypeahead active class(navigating through keyUp and Down)?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, typeahead

This is the official ngTypeahead plunker

http://embed.plnkr.co/gV6kMSRlogjBKnh3JHU3/

This is the github link 
https://github.com/orizens/ngx-typeahead

[image]

This is staticList in ngxTypeahead
While navigating with arrows keyUp and down , I have an issue.

If the number of typeahed results is 5, so when i navigate through options using keyDown, after reaching 5th , if i press keyDown it should highlight first result right? But resolveNextIndex  (as added in the image)  has topLimit as 9 and bottom limit as 0 it is calculated 10 times and hence adding activeRsult i.e highlighting the selected option doesnt work properly.
[image]

[image]

How can i resolve this?

Is there any way to customize this adding active button?

Because i need typeahead like below.

- Initially no results should be highlighted.
- Only if the user presses keyUp the hightLighting should happen from bottom to top since my inputbox is in the bottom of the screen.
- After navigating by keys to the end of the typeahead results, if i press keyDown again it should navigate to top of the result. It shoould be according to the length of the results.

Is there any other library suiting my need or can i customize this ngxTypeahed?

Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I modified the source and and importing locally.
I added one more parameter for results length and dynamically changing the topLimit

```
ngx-typeahead.component

    navigateWithArrows(elementObs: Observable<{}>) {
        return elementObs
          .filter((e: any) => validateArrowKeys(e.keyCode))
          .map((e: any) => e.keyCode)
          .subscribe((keyCode: number) => {
            this.suggestionIndex = resolveNextIndex(
              this.suggestionIndex,**this.resultsLength**,
              keyCode === Key.ArrowUp
            );
            this.showSuggestions = true;
            this.cdr.markForCheck();
          });
      }

  listenAndSuggest() {
    return Observable.fromEvent(this.element.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .filter((e: any) => validateNonCharKeyCode(e.keyCode))
      .map((e: any) => e.target.value)
      .debounceTime(300)
      .concat()
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .filter((query: string) => query.length > 0)
      .switchMap((query: string) => this.suggest(query))
      .subscribe((results: string[]) => {
        this.results = results;
        **this.resultsLength = results.length-1;**
        this.showSuggestions = true;
        this.suggestionIndex = 0;
        this.cdr.markForCheck();
      });
  }
```

This is ngx-typeahead.util

```
export function resolveNextIndex(currentIndex: number, **resultsLength: number,** stepUp: boolean) {
  const step = stepUp ? 1 : -1;
  **const topLimit = resultsLength;**
  const bottomLimit = 0;
  const currentResultIndex = currentIndex + step;
  let resultIndex = currentResultIndex;
  if (currentResultIndex === topLimit + 1) {
    resultIndex = bottomLimit;
  }
  if (currentResultIndex === bottomLimit - 1) {
    resultIndex = topLimit;
  }
  return resultIndex;
}
```